# a, b = input(), input() | переменная b пуста

Tags: python

Хочу создать две переменные и записать в них данные от пользователя.

```
a, b = input(), input()
print(f'{a=}, {b=}')
```

Когда запускаю программу:

*some1*
*some2*
**a='some1', b=''**

Почему переменная b не записывает данные, как это исправить?

Comment: Небось  пишарм )

Comment: Спасибо, я всё понял и проблему решил.

Answer (score 0):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1FHIUnBVkEjM6@gtERDU0cBytDkKijKzCvRSFOvTqzVUahOqlXX/P@/sLCQq7y8HAA)

```
a, b = input(), input()
print(f'{a}, {b}')
```

```
qqq
www
```

```
qqq, www
```